# Possible reasons for tellg() failing?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, line-endings

`ifstream::tellg()` is returning -13 for a certain file.

Basically, I wrote a utility that analyzes some source code; I open all files alphabetically, I start with "Apple.cpp" and it works perfectly.. But when it gets to "Conversion.cpp", always on the same file, after reading one line successfully tellg() returns -13.

The code in question is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) { /* For each .cpp and .h file */
   TextIFile f(files[i]);
   while (!f.AtEof()) // When it gets to conversion.cpp (not on the others)
                      // first is always successful, second always fails
      lines.push_back(f.ReadLine());
```

The code for `AtEof` is:

```
    bool AtEof() {
        if (mFile.tellg() < 0)
            FATAL(format("DEBUG - tellg(): %d") % mFile.tellg());
        if (mFile.tellg() >= GetSize())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

After it reads successfully the first line of Conversion.cpp, it always crashes with `DEBUG - tellg(): -13`.

This is the whole `TextIFile` class (wrote by me, the error may be there):

```
class TextIFile
{
public:
    TextIFile(const string& path) : mPath(path), mSize(0) {
        mFile.open(path.c_str(), std::ios::in);

        if (!mFile.is_open())
            FATAL(format("Cannot open %s: %s") % path.c_str() % strerror(errno));
    }

    string GetPath() const { return mPath; }
    size_t GetSize() { if (mSize) return mSize; const size_t current_position = mFile.tellg(); mFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end); mSize = mFile.tellg(); mFile.seekg(current_position); return mSize; }

    bool AtEof() {
        if (mFile.tellg() < 0)
            FATAL(format("DEBUG - tellg(): %d") % mFile.tellg());
        if (mFile.tellg() >= GetSize())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    string ReadLine() {
        string ret;
        getline(mFile, ret);
        CheckErrors();
        return ret;
    }

    string ReadWhole() {
        string ret((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(mFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        CheckErrors();
        return ret;
    }

private:
    void CheckErrors() {
        if (!mFile.good())
            FATAL(format("An error has occured while performing an I/O operation on %s") % mPath);
    }

    const string mPath;
    ifstream mFile;
    size_t mSize;
};
```

Platform is Visual Studio, 32 bit, Windows.

*Edit:* Works on Linux.

*Edit:* I found the cause: line endings. Both Conversion and Guid and others had \n instead of \r\n. I saved them with \r\n instead and it worked. Still, this is not supposed to happen is it?

Comment: iostreams sux. use something else :P

Comment: Is it always this file or the Nth file opened?  IOW, if you renamed conversion.cpp so it fell somewhere else in your sorted list would it still be the file to fail?

Comment: Just out of interest, how long is `Conversion.cpp` and how long was the first line read?

Comment: @Duck: renamed, it failed with Guid.h now.. Way down the list (there are ~10 files in between)

Comment: @Charles Bailey: this is Conversion.cpp - http://codepad.org/yfHwXD1h . The first line is /****...****/. Every single file in the project starts with that line.

Comment: (PS, it works on linux and it's all I care about.. Also it will always be executed supervised by me so if it stops working suddenly I won't get in trouble. So I don't "need" to fix it anymore, but I'm still curious)

Comment: @Andreas Bonini: What I meant is how many characters were in the line as read by your code?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: all of them. Anyways I found the cause: line endings. Both Conversion and Guid and others had \n instead of \r\n. Still, this is not supposed to happen is it ?

Comment: That's where I was heading. If you'd opened in `binary` mode you probably would have found a more orthodox number of lines.

Comment: Just out of interest, what did you expect? Your code read the one line (consisting of the whole file), then `tellg` returns an "off the end" value. In text mode you can't assume anything about the file positions returned by `tellg`, you can only pass them to `seekg` unaltered. Using `< 0` doesn't have well defined behaviour.

Comment: But it's not opened with std::ios::bin. It's supposed to automatically convert \n to \r\n, or at least that's what I thought and that's what it does if you write a\n.

Comment: And it doesn't read the whole file.. It reads that ONE line.

Comment: OK, it looks like my suposition was wrong. It looks like a raw `\n` is still treated like a newline even in text mode; I suspect that it's just giving the fpos positions "unusual" values as a consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to guess without knowing exactly what's in `Conversion.cpp`. However, using `<` with stream positions is not defined by the standard. You might want to consider an explicit cast to the correct integer type before formatting it; I don't know what formatting `FATAL` and `format()` expect to perform or how the `%` operator is overloaded. Stream positions don't have to map in a predicatable way to integers, certainly not if the file isn't opened in binary mode.

You might want to consider an alternative implementation for `AtEof()`. Say something like:

```
bool AtEof()
{
    return mFile.peek() == ifstream::traits_type::eof();
}
```

Comment: format() is boost::format.. Looking inside mFile with the VS debugger _Fpos is -13 ...